# Gap after uptade android launcher

Tags: android, kotlin, android-launcher

I have a custom android launcher and inner app store, which is in same package as launcher. After downloading a new version of launcher from store its possible to use deafult android before sb click home button - then launcher is pinned again.
I want to automatically open our launcher just after install new version.
I cannot use other applications.